# Change Default Tabbing Structure for Classes in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-formatting

My preferred tabbing structure for classes in C++ doesn't match Visual Studio's (2013), and I always have to manually correct it.  For example, my structure is as follows:

```
class CExample
{
    public:
        CExample();
        ~CExample();
};
```

When I type this in, Visual Studio auto-corrects it to this:

```
class CExample
{
public:
    CExample();
    ~CExample();
};
```

Note that it pulls back "public" and everything else by a full tab.  I don't like this, so I have to go and manually re-indent everything.  Then, if I copy and paste this class somewhere else, it re-introduces the default tabbing and I have to manually fix it again.

I don't want to turn off all auto-correction or auto-formatting - it's just this specific case (tab formatting of classes) that I want to change (and ideally "fix," rather than just disable).

Is there a template or something I can adjust, so that Visual Studio uses my "style" in this case, rather than its own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I suggest is to simply highlight everything and hit tab. 
This will indent the whole chunk of code instead of replacing it with a tab.

You can use the same method to "unindent" a chunk of code with shift tab

Comment: That's what I do now, but I'd rather not have to "fix" a copy-and-paste.  If it looks one way and I copy and paste it, then the pasted version should look the same as what I copied.  Having to manually fix it by highlighting and tabbing sort of undermines the purpose of "copy and pasting."

Answer (score 0):

You can change the indentations of the access specifiers, but there doesn't seem to be an option for the lines after them.

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Indentation -> Indent access specifiers